# App Deployment Container Size vs Quantity

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, server, containers, galaxy

I am learning how to deploy a meteor app on galaxy and I am really confused by all this container stuff.

I am trying to understand when it would be better to scale an app by increasing container size rather than by adding more containers.

If I had lightweight chat room website for example. Why would I ever need to upgrade the container size if I can just add more small containers. In the end isn't the sum of processing power what matters?

`2 x 0.5 containers = 1 x 1 container`

The cost of doing it either way is the same.

Also, if a user modifies the database while using the app in one container, won't the other instances of the app running on other containers take a while to notice the change? If users on different containers were chatting together it would be a problem wouldn't it? How would you avoid it?

The only way I can make sense of this is:
Either lack of CPU and RAM, or capacity to handle parallel requests are going to create a need to scale.
If the app receives too much traffic you get more containers.
If the app uses too much CPU and RAM you get a bigger container.

But how can app ever get too big to fit in one container? Won't the CPU and RAM used by the app be related to how many users are using that instance of the app. Couldn't you just solve the problem by adding more containers and spreading out the users and decreasing CPU and RAM usage this way.

And why would you need to get more containers to handle more requests. Won't a bigger container also handle more requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are asking is too broad to answer. In your case both strategies increasing container size (or vertical scaling) and adding more container (or horizontal scaling) will work if implemented effectively.

But preferring horizontal scaling is the best option. When you launch a cluster of containers they run behind AWS Elastic Loadbalancer and if you enable sticky sessions there will be no any problem in chat rooms.

Read this

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Also this is quiet good to read.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/powering-your-amazon-ecs-clusters-with-spot-fleet/

Then the question of database, I assume you will be using a parent database for your app so all the containers will be reading from same DB so do not worry about the changes applied from one container and seeing those changes applied from other container if proper DB optimization is in place there will be no any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why would you say horizontal scaling is better?